# Alphabetical pagination with kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

I'm trying to get alphabetical pagination - so my guidelines will be listed (and grouped) alphabetically and the pagination at the top will be an alphabetical list.  So far I have:

guidelines_controller.rb

```
def index
    if params[:search].present?
    @search = Sunspot.search(Guideline) do  
      fulltext params[:search]
    end
    @guidelines = @search.results
  else

    @guidelines = Guideline.order(:title).page(params[:page]).per(5).to_a.group_by{|u|u.title[0].upcase}

  end
```

index.html view

```
<%= paginate @guidelines %>
<% @guidelines.keys.sort.each do |starting_letter| %>
            <h3>
            <%= link_to starting_letter, {:action => :browse, :controller =>:index, :letter => starting_letter } %>
</h3>

                <% @guidelines[starting_letter].each do |guideline| %>
```

and then the rest of the view

This is giving me the error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `current_page' for #<Hash:0x007fd974700148>):
    1: <%= paginate @guidelines %>
    2: 
    3: <div class="page-header">
    4:  <% if @search %>
  app/views/guidelines/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_guidelines_index_html_erb___4442223584034894893_70285969096020'
  app/controllers/guidelines_controller.rb:25:in `index'
```

Am I anywhere close to a solution?  Thanks

Comment: You cannot paginate a hash, which @guidelines is.

Comment: ah ok.  I guess that's why it was fine before I added to_a

Comment: I'm still not sure how to solve this though...

Answer (score 1):

You could use kaminaris array wrapper class: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object

So this line might look like this:

```
@guidelines = Kaminari.paginate_array(Guideline.order(:title).to_a.group_by{|u|u.title[0].upcase}).page(params[:page]).per(5)
```

Note: this is totally untested and off the top of my head.